# React State value call

Tags: reactjs, web, bootstrap-4, frontend

I want to create a form and save some values.
I have this constructor code :

```
  constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {value: ''};

this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);}
```

and have handleChange function:

```
  handleChange(event) {
this.setState({value: event.target.value});}
```

and have handleSubmit function:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
event.preventDefault();}
```

the handleSubmit function there is error :

> Property 'value' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339).

How to slove it ?

Here is full code:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the error
[image]

Comment: put you entire code here

Comment: @praga2050 Done

Comment: i dont see any issue here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ie2rt6 See this stackblitz

Comment: @praga2050 I have attached the error photo

Comment: looks like more of IDE issue. Did u try running yarn start or npm start and see if this error showing up in browser.

Comment: @praga2050 Can't start app with this error

Comment: gotcha you using typescript for React

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using typescript you need to do something like this. Have a look at this stackBlitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-gfcdog

```
import React from "react";

interface State{
  value? : string
}

export default class NameForm extends React.Component<{},State> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event: any) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event: any) {
    alert("A name was submitted: " + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```